# In which countries is Pokemon Go available?

Tags: pokemon-go

In which countries can I play Pokemon Go?
Is it available in all countries or only in a few?

Comment: If you sideload the .apk, you can play in any country. Just use a reputable source to avoid getting malware.

Comment: @gre_gor There may not be Pokestops or actual Pokemon spawns in other countries, though.

Comment: There are pokestops if there are portals in ingress

Comment: There is a site where you can check this: http://is-pokemon-go-available.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Bulbapedia, [this is the list of the countries](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_GO_now_available_throughout_most_of_Europe) where Pokémon GO is available.

> The freemium mobile game Pokémon GO is now available for iOS and Android in 26 more European countries.
>   Specifically, it is now available in Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, Greece, Greenland, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Sweden, and Switzerland.
>
> This follows its release last week in Australia, New Zealand, and the United States; its release three days ago in Germany; and its release two days ago in the United Kingdom; and its release yesterday in Italy, Spain, and Portugal. Notably, it is still not available in France, Turkey or Russia.
>
> As previously reported, the game is stated to be coming soon to Japan, Canada, and Latin and South America.

Also, you can check the avalability from [this website: http://www.releases.com/](http://www.releases.com/availability/pokemon-go)

Answer (score 11):

> Pokemon Go is out in Australia, New Zealand, Japan, and is slowly
>   rolling out across the United States and other countries. Just be
>   patient and regularly check your app store/Google play.
>
> Be warned anywhere boasting to get you the game now(before it is
>   available normally for you) could lead to you potentially downloading
>   Malware on your phone or (less likely but still a possiblity) being
>   banned from ever playing the game on your device. So just be patient,
>   the game should be worldwide soon.

[Unofficial Source](https://www.facebook.com/PokemonGoOnline/posts/1182752045109449)

> Pokémon GO - Get up and go!Break out the sneakers and Poké Balls!
>   Pokémon GO is now available in the US, Australia and New Zealand on
>   iPhone and Android devices. Coming to other countries soon!

[Official Source](https://www.facebook.com/nianticlabs/videos/vb.326421100852161/594571270703808/?type=2&theater)

Update:
Germany and UK also seems to be out now.

Update:
Italy and The Netherlands should be out now too. Check this website for future updates: https://www.ispokemongoavailableyet.com/

Comment: You beat me with 1 minute :) But we've used different sources.

Comment: What a time to live in when Facebook is consideres as a source lol -.-'

Comment: @AntoineHejlík Well it's the official Facebook page, and companies usually take their social media and PR very seriously. Besides this fact, I grabbed the unofficial source because community reports work faster in this scenario, as no roadmap/timeline regarding the roll out is available from official sources.

As you can see in the answers, the unofficial source has more countries reported that are active.

Comment: Ya it is not "bad",  just hilarious :)

Comment: How possibly you can ban a device permanently? There's nothing like being banned for downloading and playing if it isn't available in your country, because there is no easy way to identify if it is the same device.

Answer (score 9):

From Niantic's [announcement page](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/launch)

> We are pleased to announce that Pokémon GO, the next evolution of Real
>   World Gaming, is now officially available on both the App Store and on
>   Google Play Store in **Australia, New Zealand and the United States**. It
>   will be available in other countries around the world in the days
>   ahead.

But this announcement doesn't explain if it's only available to install and play in those countries or if you can install the app in those countries and travel abroad and be able to play in different countries, too. This question has to be answered by the community. There isn't any official statement about it, yet.

Comment: I am in CZE and here it says that app is not compatible with device (even it should be), but according to some webpages this is shown because country is not compatible. Don't know if it is by IP, by account selection of country (that one is probable) or language settings or so.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík If you visit the play store on your desktop browser and press the "Install" button to list your phones it will show this message: "This item cannot be installed in your device's country". However, I installed the app from elsewhere and it works for now, even has translated German text.

Answer (score 4):

The website [MMO Server Status](http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemongo) shows the state of the servers of a lot of countries, telling us where it has been released and where it hasn't.

[image: Picture of the Pokemon GO page on this website as of July 27.]

Edit: On August 18th 2016, the situation is as shown in the image below:
[image: Picture of the Pokemon GO page on this website as of August 18.]

Answer (score 3):

I'm an American living in Germany & I've been able to download and play the game from the Apple app store. I've had my phone and my itunes acct since living in the US but I have a German SIM in.

Answer (score 3):

As of 14th July 2016, it's [now officially available in the UK](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-36793610).