# Is there any reason I don't see any building in the game?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am living in India (Tripura, Belonia). I can't seem to be able to see any buildings in the game, that being Pokéstops or gyms. Could this be a bug, or is there any other reason I would not be able to see those?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Maybe your area is too rural?

Comment: Is Pokémon Go [officially available](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272729) in India yet? Did you download it from an official source, or did you have to side-load the game to get it on your phone?

Comment: Even in the USA, a lot of rural areas don't have any Pokéstops or gyms within visual range on the map. Going into town helps a *lot*. Historical markers and parks (even in rural areas) are also good places.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible reasons for not being able to see anything

- Belonia is in a rural area with population of about 25000 (info from Google), so there might not be any landmarks and parks around, since there's also forest everywhere. Ask other people around you that play if they see any buildings on theirs for confirmation. Or, *rural areas tend to not have Pokestops or gyms.*
- If you see roads and/or paths, but no buildings, your game is most likely working but there's nothing there, or

  - If your internet connection is slow, Pokestops and Gyms will load, but slowly.
- If you *don't* see roads and/or paths, the GPS could not locate you (or you are at a place without marked roads/paths)
- Very rarely, it could just be a temporary bug. If checking back later doesn't solve the problem, then your issue is most likely one of the above reasons.